# What function(s) to be used to generate Salt on Windows Mobile 6

Tags: passwords, mobile, password-policy

I am looking for THE or a real function I can use to generate salt for my mobile app on Windows Mobile. In case I am not abusing in this request but in the future I plan as well the same app for BlackBerry so in case also you can point me out to the BlackBerry function I would be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

[net.rim.device.api.crypto.FIPS186PseudoRandomSource](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/FIPS186PseudoRandomSource.html)